# Set button config to act differently in different panels

Tags: button, extjs

I have a button which i have rendered twice in two different panels. I am trying to make this button act differently when clicked from these panels. Say, When this button is clicked from panel 1, it has to do something and when clicked from panel 2. it has to do something else.

For example, I have created a fiddle, wherein, the button when clciked from panel 1 should alert me saying Panel 1 was clicked, but when clicked from panel 2, it has to alert me saying Panel 2 was clicked.

Is this doable. If so, how do i do this?

Here is the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1v2m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a parameter inside your button handler as "btn" or whatever name suits you.

Then do

```
btn.ownerCt.config.$initParent.title
```

it will give you the title of the parent panel where it comes from. Happy Learning :)